# Determining if a maximum Independent set is in FPT when parameterized

Tags: parameterized-complexity

I'm confused to if there exists an algorithm that can solve the below maximum independent set in polynomial time where it is parameterized by a k value.

maximum independent set

Input: A graph G with weight and a positive integer K
Output: A safe set of maximum total value that uses at most k integers

say I have these parameters:

- n, the number of vertices in graph G
- m, the maximum degree of any vertex in the graph G
- w, the number of different weights for edges

does there exists an algorithm that can find the answer in polynomial time where maximum independent set is parameterized by each of the above? Why or why not?

Comment: What do you think? Can you solve any of the three?

Comment: A good hint when you're quickly trying to check if a problem could be FPT parameterized by a parameter $p$, is to think: if $p = 1$, can I solve the problem quickly? How? If $p = 3$, can I solve the problem quickly? etc. If the answer to any of these is no, then usually the answer is not FPT. You can also ask yourself, if I allow an algorithm in time $O(2^p)$, is there something interesting I can do? Hope this helps, your problems can all be solved with this simple insights :)